# ERB: Creating dropdown menus and correctly linking to their respective IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, indexing, erb

In my **controller.rb** I have the following code:

```
@teams = Team.all
```

Here is some sample **output**:

```
<Team id: 1, name: "Eastside", nick: "Bunnies", api_team_id: 3235, created_at: "2013-01-18    
 21:19:24", updated_at: "2013-01-18 21:19:24">
<Team id: 2, name: "Westside", nick: "Turtles", api_team_id: 3235, created_at: "2013-01-18     
 21:19:24", updated_at: "2013-01-18 21:19:24">
<Team id: 3, name: "Northside", nick: "Birds", api_team_id: 3235, created_at: "2013-01-18   
 21:19:24", updated_at: "2013-01-18 21:19:24">
```

How can I create a dropdown list that will display Team.name and Team.nick for each item? 
Also, how can I link_to the team's respective team.id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read some Rails tutorials first.

For the dropdown menu:

```
#in your view
<%= select_tag 'team_id', options_for_select(@teams.map{|team| ["#{team.name} #{team.nick}", team.id] }) %>
```

About the `link_to` the team's show page, I assume you declared your resources in your routes.rb. If so, you should have the 4 CRUD Action (Create Retrieve Update Delete).
Then if everything is set up correctly, you could do:

```
<% team = Team.first %>
<%= link_to team.name, team_path(team) %>
```

Comment: You're right Mr.Yoshi, I do need to read up on some tutorials. Thanks for the solution.